# django html file is not showing

Tags: python, django

It keeps showing `index.html` file instead of `register.html` file which is supposed to display register form.

my views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.shortcuts import render
from seany_user.forms import registerform

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

class registerview(FormView):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = registerform
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class registerform(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        error_messages={
            'required': 'enter your goddamn email'
        },
        max_length=64, label='email'
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        error_messages={
            'required': 'enter your password'
        },
        widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='password'
    )
    re_password = forms.CharField(
        error_messages={
            'required': 'enter your password'
        },
        widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='confirm password'
    )
```

register.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block contents %}
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-12 text-center">
    <h1>register</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-12">
    {{ error }}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-12">
    <form method="POST" action=".">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
          placeholder="{{ field.label }}" name="{{ field.name }}" />
      </div>
      {% if field.errors %}
      <span style="color: red">{{ field.errors }}</span>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">로그인</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block contents %}
Hello world!
{% endblock %}
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from seany_user.views import index, registerview
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', index),
    url(r'^register/', registerview.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Please, can you paste your urls.py and tell which URL are you trying in the browser?

Comment: Show what you have added in your `urls.py`

Comment: i updated and /register url. it keeps showing index html

Comment: if you visit https://127.0.0.1:8000 the browser will point to index.html page.
if yo visit https://127.0.0.1:8000/register the browser will point to register.html ..

What exactly would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You need to terminate your URLs. Currently your index URL matches any string, including "register". It should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^register/$', registerview.as_view()),
]
```

or, better, use the new path syntax:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('register/', registerview.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: (And/or reorder the urls so the `index` route is last.)